# How to use React-Router-Dom Link component with RouterProvider properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm learning the latest version of React and React-Router-Dom, I create a simple demo app.

Home.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

About.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>About</div>
  )
}

export default About
```

index.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    element: <About />
  }
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </RouterProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

but it doesn't display the link, it just displays the content in `Home` or `About` component. No errors in the console.

I have searched a lot and didn't find what's the problem of the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use link inside `RouterProvider` use it in any component.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

In Home you can create link

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score -1):

*Please make sure to check your package.json file to ensure that you have successfully installed react, react-dom, and react-router-dom. If they are installed correctly, you can import ReactDOM like this: 'import ReactDOM from "react-dom"'. If still it is not working, then importing Outlet from react-router-dom. You are not using an Outlet component to specify where the matched content should be rendered. In that case, you should wrap your Link tag in an Outlet component like this:*

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      <Outlet />
    </RouterProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
```